# Can you override the iPhone keyboard locale at runtime?

Tags: iphone, internationalization

I need to create an iPhone app that supports user input in multiple languages.  The user needs to be able to change his input language at runtime between English, Spanish, Chinese, Japanese, etc.  Is there any way through the iPhone SDK to display a keyboard for a language other than the user's default language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't change the keyboard programmatically.

BUT you can completely ignore the system keyboard and use your own custom keyboard. If you design your keyboard from scratch, you can then have complete control of it.

It's a lot of work, but since I have seen a few apps using custom keyboards I guess it's OK with Apple rules.

Answer (score 1):

No, but note that if the user has turned on more than one keyboard in their Settings, there's a small button next to the spacebar that lets them switch languages.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, your application cannot control the user’s preferred language (and thus the keyboard’s input method) - there is no programmatic control for this.